# How to return errors from a Python gRPC interceptor?

Tags: python, grpc, interceptor

How do I check authentication in this interceptor and reject the request with an authentication error?

```py
class Authentication(grpc.ServerInterceptor):
    def intercept_service(self, continuation, details):
        # How to raise an error?
```

I've seen [this example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/interceptors/default_value/default_value_client_interceptor.py) but this appears to be an older style of writing interceptors. I'm extending the `grpc.ServerInterceptor` class and passing the interceptor to the server [like this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio/grpc/__init__.py#L2159-L2162). Is it possible to return an authentication error from an interceptor written like this?

Answer (score 0):

The example you are referring to is for client interceptor.

[This example of server interceptor](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/45aecbe3555c1da36cfbfaff0622646923d5137c/examples/python/interceptors/headers/request_header_validator_interceptor.py) should work for you:

```
"""Interceptor that ensures a specific header is present."""

import grpc


def _unary_unary_rpc_terminator(code, details):
    def terminate(ignored_request, context):
        context.abort(code, details)

    return grpc.unary_unary_rpc_method_handler(terminate)


class RequestHeaderValidatorInterceptor(grpc.ServerInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, header, value, code, details):
        self._header = header
        self._value = value
        self._terminator = _unary_unary_rpc_terminator(code, details)

    def intercept_service(self, continuation, handler_call_details):
        if (
            self._header,
            self._value,
        ) in handler_call_details.invocation_metadata:
            return continuation(handler_call_details)
        else:
            return self._terminator
```

Use UNAUTHENTICATED status code for authentication errors and PERMISSION_DENIED for authorization errors.